# Can Create a New primitive datatype in Java

Tags: java, types

First thing I want to clarify here, this question is because of curiosity. I am not facing any issue.

There are many primitive types available in Java `byte`, `short`, `int`, etc. Now suppose I want to create a new primitive type (e.g. `mediumint` or anything else). Can we do that?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 13):

Primitive types are the ones defined by the language itself. In `Java` you can only define new types  as `Classes` all derived from the common base class called `Object`.

Comment: whats stopping him from playing around with the original code?

Comment: You can mess with the source of a JVM, but it wouldn't be Java as Java is defined by the Java language specification (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Comment: In addition to the answer: in some similar languages (e.g. C#) you can define your own objects which are passed by value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.110).aspx), which resemble primitives in some ways. But in Java you can't.

Comment: @dtech: from my point of view C#'s structs are more similar to classes than primitive data. They are simple collections of primitive data and methods. The only difference is that are passed by value like you pointed out.

Comment: @Heisenbug You could also argue that in a reasonable OOP language objects that are passed by value are primitives. E.g. in C# and Ruby all "primitives" (like int, long) are objects too. If Java would've made this decision auto-boxing wouldn't have been necessary, it is a thing some see as a design flaw of Java (http://www.research.ibm.com/people/a/alpert/ptch/ptch.html)

Comment: @dtech: maybe you don't consider C++ a "reasonable OOP language" :). But in C++ you can pass objects either by value or reference.

Comment: @Heisenbug Maybe "modern" would be more a better description. C++ isn't really a fair comparison, as it was designed to be source (and binary) compatible with C and as such `needed` primitives.

Comment: I think being a scalar should be a necessary condition for being a primitive, at least by the spirit of the word as used in the jls.

Answer (score 5):

You could, but then it wouldn't be Java anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Simply No, You can not create primitive datatype.

Primitive datatype means which are provided and existed in language feature. Basically Java support this for performance reason and perform arithmetic operation.

You can create a user defined datatype using concept of `class` and `object`.

Answer (score 2):

You all are wrong.
Yes. You can.
As a rule, you do not need a completely new primitive type. So, you don't need to rebuild JVM.
Usually, you only need to "pack" or "cast" your new primitive type to an existing and define some operations like "+" with its wrapper.

You can do it relatively simply with original JVM, but with your own Java compiler.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create your own primitive datatype.

As the Java documentation explains: [A primitive type is predefined by the language and is named by a reserved keyword.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)