# How to create a special data type?

Tags: java, binary, custom-data-type

I'm trying to create a Binary class in Java (there already is one- but I want to implement my own), but I'm not sure how to create Binary as it's own data type.

I haven't tried anything major- I'm not even sure where to start doing this.

This is a short code snippet showing how I currently display the Binary numbers (using String).

```java
public class Binary{
    String biNum = "0000000";

    public Binary(){
        biNum = "00000000";
    }
```

My goal here is to make it so, in a simple matter, I can display repetitive zeroes without using String or DecimalFormat. As an example, String is an object that puts multiple characters together- but it's like it's own data type. You can just type the characters and it will accept them in that long string. I want to be able to do something like `Binary binaryNumber = 01010101;`. I hope you understand what I'm getting at-- and I'm sorry for essentially asking you to solve my problems. This is just a really new concept to me, and I'm not even sure if it can be done. There doesn't need to be a definitive answer; I just need some sort of guidance on how to start doing something like this.

Comment: Java has binary literals: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123645/can-create-a-new-primitive-datatype-in-java) question. It possibly answers yours. 
As @NotaJD mentioned you can utilize binary literals if it's just the functionality you're after. If you're trying to _simulate_ / _model_ a binary data type, you can do this with a class. All you lose out on is some faster syntax for assigning values. Basically all data types are a way of storing `Byte` (or an array of bytes) and doing something with said data.

Comment: Integers etc are already binary types... You seem to have a X-Y problem here.

Comment: @Batman and NotADJ, that answers my questions yes- I was trying to implement some kind of class data type like Integer compared to int. The primitive byte data type should work perfectly though. Thank you for the links and explanations. Cheers.